# “Will [arming/armed] teachers make schools safer?”

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> "Will **arming teachers** make schools safer?"

I think that the author should have used **armed teachers** in this sentence.

If it is grammatically correct, what is the difference between the two usages, concerning the means.

Here is the news link;
http://www.npr.org/sections/ed/2017/06/25/534230962/colorado-teachers-get-gun-training-as-first-responders

Comment: "Arming teachers" means the action of providing teachers with firearms. The writer is asking whether such a policy would make schools safer. It is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Remember that armed teachers are a result of arming them, which is an activity.  The training involved in arming is more than the weapon itself. 
 Arming also implies that someone is performing that action. Essentially, *we* are arming them, and that's controversial.

Comment: It is grammatically correct, but it is still horrible because it is grammatically correct in more than one way actually. I parse it as "will teachers who give firearms to their pupils make schools safer". Like WTF man.

Comment: The sentence says nothing about arming pupils.

Comment: @KateBunting Agreed; however, Reg might be joking a bit by suggesting that "arming" is an adjective, thus: *teachers who arm [students]*.

Answer (score 1):

> "Will **arming teachers** make schools safer?"

This question is about the **decision** / **process** to provide guns / weapons / arms to teachers, for the purpose to make schools safer.

---

> "Will **armed teachers** make schools safer?"

This question is about the **teachers which carry guns / arms**, again for the purpose of ensuring safety.

---

Both ways are grammatically correct and both can be used, having ultimately similar meanings - the result of **arming teachers** is **armed teachers**.

Answer (score -2):

Either-or. It just depends on whether you want to convey an action or a state/quality. However, I agree with the author's choice to use "arming", because it implies that teachers are not yet armed. If you were to say "Will armed teachers make schools safer?", it *could* carry with it an implication that some teachers are presently (presumably) breaking the law and possessing firearms in .

But to answer your question succinctly, yes, both the author's and your wording is correct.